# React why pass down functions to components anyway?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am just wondering, why do we define every component function in one place (e.g index.js) and then pass those functions down the components? Does that make any sense?

E.g I want to define a click handler for a list button component, and another click handler for some forms button component, why would I define them all in one place? Isn't the divide-and-conquer approach better?

I mean, why would I not just define my click handlers in the components themselves, where they belong? beside the fact, that everything in one place gets messy and hard to upkeep...

Comment: IMO short story: Since data is bound one-way only,  controlling state at the top of the component tree lets you send state wherever you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to define a click handler for a list button component, and another click handler for some forms button component, why would I define them all in one place?

Because of the nature of the unidirectional data flow that React employs, state flows down the tree and events (i.e. changes) are passed back up via handlers such as the ones you mention. Components deep down in the tree can (or rather, should) only propagate changes back up via clickHandlers and the like.

The reason that handlers are often defined together in only a few places is because those places typically represent points where common state is shared, so the events that update that state need to be handled there.

Comment: ok but lets assume a click has an effect only in the sub-component where the click is being executed, e.g color something differently in the sub-component, without needing to track some state... would it then make sense to implement the function in the sub-component only? or not?

Comment: If nothing else needs to know that the subcomponent state has changed then it can stay local to it, sure. Lately I've been using Redux for any app-wide state and hooks for local component-level stuff. It's a good combiniation.

Comment: ok nice that ansers my question, and it makes sense of course... I totally forgot that most things have a state and state is often changed by sub-components but kept track of (or shows its effects) in the top-level component only ;)